# Uncounted close vote?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

I cast a close vote on this question: [Simplify expression in Swift playground](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77531/simplify-expression-in-swift-playground), or at least that's what is claimed and is preventing me from casting a close vote now.

[image]

Yet the question appears to have zero close votes cast on it?

I know that if the question were closed after I voted to close then reopened, my close vote would be gone, and this would be correct.  And while this question has been closed and (inappropriately) re-opened, my close vote is supposedly after this closing and re-opening occurred.

[image]

So, what's going on here?  Why doesn't my close vote show up?

(Whether or not the question needs to be closed might be another meta question, so please don't get off-topic with answers here.  This question is strictly about a close vote that's not appearing.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cast that close vote on `Jan 16 at 0:02`, and it 'aged away' on `Jan 20 at 3:00`.

[Close votes expire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away), and you cannot close-vote twice on the same question.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.